# Add status to the response using NestJS

Tags: nestjs

I am using NestJS and wondering how would you add a status to the response object. Say I have this controller method:

```
  @Get()
  ping(): string {
    return this.appService.ping();
  }
```

That return a string like '24 March 2020 16:56:07'. What I want is to add the status code to the response so my response and error message so the response would looks looks like this:

```
{
  result: "24 March 2020 16:56:07"
  status: "OK"
  errorMessage: ""
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve that using some nestjs built in features?

UPDATE:
The solution proposed by @Hitech-Hitesh it is not something I am looking for, I want to buildup the response object automatically so I do just return result from the controller method `return this.appService.ping();` and then `something else taking place` and builds up the response object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in your service file like this >

```js
  getData(): Message {
    // return { message: 'Welcome to api!' };
    return { message: '' };
  }
  ping() {
    if (this.getData().message !== '') {
      return { status: 'OK', errorMessage: '', result: this.getData().message };
    }
    else {
      return { status: 'FAIL', errorMessage: 'Not able to fetch the result. Please try again later', result: '' };
    }
  }
```

when the ping file is called from the controller it will directly give the result

```js
  @Get()
  ping(): any {
    return this.appService.ping();
  }
```

You can do this directly in your controller also but checking the service response.

```js
  @Get()
  ping(): any {
    const pingServiceResponse = this.appService.ping();
    if (pingServiceResponse !== '')
      return { status: 'OK', errorMessage: '', result: pingServiceResponse };
    else
      return { status: 'FAIL', errorMessage: 'Not able to fetch the result. Please try again later', result: pingServiceResponse };

    // return this.appService.ping();
  }
```

Comment: I want to build up such a response object automatically without handcode that for every call, sorry if it was not clear enough.